# How to redirect the page after rewrite the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite the URL so I have used the below code  in my htaccess which is working

```
RewriteRule ^products/part/pumps/?$ pumps.php [L,NC]
```

if someone tries to access the url link `exmple.com/products/part/pumps/` then it's showing the `pumps.php` data.

Now my issue is if some try to access the page example.com/pumps.php then how can I redirect to this link `exmple.com/products/part/pumps/`

I have tried but getting a redirecting error

```
Redirect 301  /pumps.php /products/part/pumps/
```

I have many pages and i have to redirect them also. sharing two example here

```
RewriteRule ^power\.php$ /products/engine/power/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^connecting\.php$ /products/connection/power/connecting/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following *before* your existing rewrite:

```
# External redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^pumps\.php$ /products/part/pumps/ [R=301,L]
```

(But test first with a 302 redirect to avoid potential caching issues.)

By checking that the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is "empty" we can redirect only direct requests from the user and not the rewritten request by the later rewrite. After the request is successfully rewritten, `REDIRECT_STATUS` has the value `200` (as in 200 OK HTTP status).

The `RewriteCond` (condtion) directive must precede every `RewriteRule` directive that triggers an external redirect.

The `Redirect` directive (part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite) is processed unconditionally and will end up redirecting the rewritten request, resulting in a redirect loop. You need to use mod_rewrite throughout.

---

#### Use the `END` flag instead of `RewriteCond` (requires Apache 2.4)

Alternatively, you can modify your existing rewrite to use the `END` flag (instead of `L`) to prevent a loop by the rewrite engine. The `RewriteCond` directive as mentioned above can then be omitted. But note that the `END` flag is only available on Apache 2.4+.

For example:

```
# External redirects
RewriteRule ^pumps\.php$ /products/part/pumps/ [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrites
RewriteRule ^products/part/pumps/?$ pumps.php [END,NC]
```

It is advisable to group all the external redirects together, before the internal rewrites.

Unfortunately, due to the varying nature of these rewrites it doesn't look like the rules can be reduced further.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I have tested your answer and it's working but also I found one issue. I have to redirect more than 10 pages but your answer redirects only one page.  if I add one more page link then getting a redirection issue.

Comment: @user9437856 Please update your question with your existing code that is causing problems. (Adding another URL/redirect should not cause a problem.) What are the URLs you need to rewrite/redirect. It may be possible to reduce the rules, depending on the URLs being written.

Comment: I have added two example codes to the question.

Comment: @user9437856 You are missing the `RewriteCond` directive? This must precede every `RewriteRule` that triggers an external redirect. The `RewriteCond` directive can be avoided by updating your existing rewrites to use the `END` flag instead (requires Apache 2.4+). I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok. so I have to change only the internal URL? instated of L i have to add END

Comment: @user9437856 Yes, as per the example in my answer.